# How to run an app always admin mode in Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, admin, administrator

I need to run DBeaver admin mode but instead of running the app via terminal, I need to run via shortcut as admin mode.

So, is it possible in Mac as in Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run the app with `sudo`(admin mode in your word) permission with the help of the built-in App: `Script Editor`.

With `Script Editor` app open, paste this line:

```
do shell script "open /System/Applications/Stickies.app" user name "YOUR_USER_NAME" password "YOUR_PASSWORD" with administrator privileges
```

I'm taking the app `Stickies.app` as an example. Replace it with your own user-mode app

When edit is done, choose `Menu` -> `File` -> `Export` to export it as an Application.

[image]

Then you will get an executable "sudo" version of your application at your exported location.

[image]

Congrats